# Convert a RDD into DataFrame after foreachRDD operation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am processing logs which using Spark Streaming. I parse the log and convert the logs into Java Map. Following is the code. 
Now I want to convert this Map into DataFrames
Any suggestion how achieve this?

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StreamingApp").setMaster("local[2]")
sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
sqlContext= new SQLContext(sc)

val lines = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://localhost:9000/test")
process(lines)


def process(lines: DStream[String]) {
 val maptorow = lines.foreachRDD(rdd=>{
  rdd.map(line => getMap(line))
  .map(p =>
  Row(p.get("column1"),
    p.get("column2"))    
    }) // how to get dataframe after this?


def getMap(logs: String): java.util.Map[String, Object] = {
    val k : java.util.Map[String, String] = parseLog(logs) 
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really get your question.

Comment: How do i filter data stream in spark streaming?

Comment: `rdd.filter(predicate)` or `dstream.filter(predicate)` ?

Comment: but maptorow val in my code is not getting converted to dataframe

Answer (score 1):

foreachRDD has no return type, hence, you shouldn't be saving maptorow and in order for you to convert it, you need to do the conversion inside the foreachRDD and then deal with each RDD by itself as a separate set of data

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)
lines.foreachRDD(rdd=>{
import sqlContext.implicits._
val maptorow = lines.foreachRDD(rdd=>{
val newRDD = rdd.map(line => getMap(line))
  .map(p =>
  Row(p.get("column1"),
    p.get("column2"))    
val myDataFrame = newRDD.toDF()
 //process myDataFrame as a DF
    })
```

Comment: Thanks . But when i tried this, I am getting compilation error "value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]"

Comment: @Alok my bad, implicits should be imported inside the foreach loop
See above

Comment: Sorry , It is still giving same error.Although sqlContext.createDataFrame(newRDD, schema) is working for me. 
Thanks'